# A cell containing the INDEX function is returning the incorrect values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula within a cell:

```
=D26-($L26*$F$3*$E$4)+INDEX($A$1:$Z$500,ROW(D27)-$S$3,18)
```

It is returning `0`, HOWEVER this is not the expected result. When I check the values of the individual terms by copy/pasting them separately into different cells here's what I get:

```
=D26-($L26*$F$3*$E$4)
```

returns `300`, which is the expected value, and

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$500,ROW(D27)-$S$3,18)
```

returns `0`, which is the expected value.

Why on earth does adding these two terms not return `300` as expected?

As some background, this is an inventory model that adjusts daily inventory based on yesterday's sales and any inventory that has arrived. The first two terms, `D26-($L26*$F$3*$E$4)`, subtract yesterday's sales. The last term, `INDEX($A$1:$Z$500,ROW(D27)-$S$3,18)`, looks back a certain number of days from the current row in order to add any inventory that is scheduled to arrive today. In this case, `$S$3` defines lookback period (i.e. the delay between ordering inventory and receiving it).

Ideally, I want to just fill down `=D26-($L26*$F$3*$E$4)+INDEX($A$1:$Z$500,ROW(D26)-$S$3,18)` for the entire year (365 rows). However, the formula typically works for the first row, but then breaks when I try to fill down. It's not an issue with non-referenced cells. I've tested the individual terms for cells many rows down and they return the expected values. It's just when combining the terms or filling down, I can't seem to get the desired result.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mention: "this works for the first row" yet you refer to row 26 in your example. Is that the first row? It would also be useful to present some data, to be able to reproduce this easily

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that the cells referenced by the `INDEX` function contained the `INDIRECT` function. Eliminating the `INDIRECT` function got rid of the problem, and I'm getting the values expected now.

Comment: Please consider deleting the question then, as this will probably not be useful to future readers.